# How can we call javascript function inside CKEditor instance?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('CKEditor1');
            var ckeditor = CKEDITOR.instances['CKEditor1'];
            ckeditor.on('key', function (event) {
                var x = event.data.keyCode;
                console.log(x);
                if (x == 13) {                  
                   Capitalize();
                }
                else if (x == 32) {
                   alert("Press enter!!!!");
                }
                function Capitalize() {
                    if (this.value.match(/^[a-z]/)) {
                        this.value = this.value.replace(/^./, function (letter) {
                            return letter.toUpperCase();
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I want to Capitalize first letter automatically after pressing enter key or space key. I just want to get my function active when user press particular key.

Comment: What is happening right now? Did you get any error or what??

Comment: No error. But letters not getting capital.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(letter.toUpperCase())` before returning `letter.toUpperCase()`, see what you get!

Comment: Its not working!!!!!